# how to avoid two empty rows at single click in gridview

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have a grid view.  If I click the add button, an empty row is created. There is more than one empty row in the grid view. Now if I click the delete button on the selected row, all the empty rows are deleted. I want to delete the selected empty row only.

thank you..please help ..

delete code is here...

```
protected void gvEmployeeDetails_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    Label lblEmpID = (Label)gvEmployeeDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lblEmpID");

    conn.Open();
    string cmdstr = "delete from EmployeeDetails where empid=@empid";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdstr, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empid", lblEmpID.Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
    BindData();
}
```

add row code here.........
in add row i want alert message if the name textbox is empty

```
  protected void gvEmployeeDetails_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName.Equals("ADD"))
    {
        TextBox txtAddEmpID = (TextBox)gvEmployeeDetails.FooterRow.FindControl("txtAddEmpID");
        TextBox txtAddName = (TextBox)gvEmployeeDetails.FooterRow.FindControl("txtAddName");
        TextBox txtAddDesignation = (TextBox)gvEmployeeDetails.FooterRow.FindControl("txtAddDesignation");
        TextBox txtAddCity = (TextBox)gvEmployeeDetails.FooterRow.FindControl("txtAddCity");
        TextBox txtAddCountry = (TextBox)gvEmployeeDetails.FooterRow.FindControl("txtAddCountry");

        conn.Open();
        string cmdstr = "insert into EmployeeDetails(empid,name,designation,city,country) values(@empid,@name,@designation,@city,@country)";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdstr, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empid", txtAddEmpID.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtAddName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@designation", txtAddDesignation.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", txtAddCity.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", txtAddCountry.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
        BindData();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you change the "empid" column to be Identity? This is done from SQL management studio and will make your column to be unique and will auto increment the values in it. After that you will remove it from the Add method and the SQL will take care of it. This will fix your problem.

In SQL you must go the the EmployeeDetails table. Choose design from your options and then go the to empid column. On it you can open Column Properties and expand the "Identity Specifications". Then change "(Is Idetity)" to "Yes" and save the table. See the screenshot below:

[image]

Then your Add code should look like that:

```
protected void gvEmployeeDetails_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName.Equals("ADD"))
    {
        TextBox txtAddName = (TextBox)gvEmployeeDetails.FooterRow.FindControl("txtAddName");
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtAddName.Text))
        {
          MessageBox.Show("Name is empty"); // or some logging, you decide
        }
        else
        {
            TextBox txtAddDesignation = (TextBox)gvEmployeeDetails.FooterRow.FindControl("txtAddDesignation");
            TextBox txtAddCity = (TextBox)gvEmployeeDetails.FooterRow.FindControl("txtAddCity");
            TextBox txtAddCountry = (TextBox)gvEmployeeDetails.FooterRow.FindControl("txtAddCountry");

            conn.Open();
            string cmdstr = "insert into EmployeeDetails(name,designation,city,country) values(@name,@designation,@city,@country)";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdstr, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtAddName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@designation", txtAddDesignation.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", txtAddCity.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", txtAddCountry.Text);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
            BindData();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to add manual ids to the employee then you must create a logic for that. One options is to add method which will read all Ids currently in the table and add the next, but this is like a duplicate to the automatic ids created by the SQL. Another option is to create a logic which will generate employee ids based on something useful to you. Do you have any logic for the employee IDs?

Comment: Then what is the problem to habe an auto increment

Comment: how to avoid add empty row here

Comment: Sorry, can you explain more? What do you mean with avoid empty row?

Comment: if i click add button without any data give it set id as rondom number and added empty data in database

Comment: If you leave the auto increment logic, the rows added in the database will always have a new ID, which will be unique. If you want to erase that and create your own custom logic, then you have to watch of already entered IDs, but that's another question. Otherwise to generate a new random number you can use the code: Random rnd = new Random(); int num = rnd.Next(x, y) // x and y are the start and the end number between which the random number will be generated.

Comment: no atansa sir i want to prevent adding empty data while identity is true it should throw error as ur name  should enter

Comment: just i want in add code if name is empty is should show alert ...thats only i want pls give code in my add code

Comment: how to give alert in add row code when name textbox is empty

Comment: See the edited code. I wrote that if the txtAddName is empty or null, then a message box will appear. You can change that to whatever you need.

Comment: what should i put response. then what should put instead of messagebox.show

Comment: I can't understand what you are trying to do? Can you explain it again?

Answer (score -1):

try this code:

```
   gvEmployeeDetails.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
```

It will Automatically delete Empty row.

Comment: where should i have to add this

Answer (score -1):

also try this one also,

```
gvEmployeeDetails.DeleteRow(Row name/index);
```

Comment: Finally bind like this, gvEmployeeDetails.databind();

Comment: Do not comment on your own reply to add elements unless replying to comments, please edit your reply and append further elements to it.

Comment: Please explain your answer to make it more useful for readers.

Comment: if i click add link without data it add empty row .so there are two empty rows in grid view if i click delete button in selected row it delete all empty rows .but i want to delete selected row only